# How can a theme be looked in sites/my_custom_website?

Tags: files

How do tell Drupal 8 to look for themes and custom modules in a directory called sites/my_custom_website?

I know this type of code is added to the themes and modules directory at the root level. I have a special case where this code needs to is separate from the git repository and away from the original build.

Comment: I guess that is nested pretty deep. It might be easier to use a symlink from `themes/mytheme` to your directory instead?

Comment: Thanks, I don't have the permissions to access that on that solution server. I am amazed that is there is not a setting in setting.php

Comment: You are aware that you can create sub-folders within the theme and module directories right? Like `modules/contrib` for standard modules and `modules/custom` for your own? I suppose that you can exclude this custom folder from the main repo with a .gitignore file.

Comment: Yep, I thought of that but I have so custom modules that i need to do that same thing too. I was hoping to add them together and add the to a private repo

Comment: you could make the `modules/custom` folder its own repository? It would include all your custom modules.

Comment: Yes that sounds like the only solution